# How to change selected value of combobox when other cell value is changed in gridview

Tags: c#, windows

I am going to create c# windows application. In my form i have one gridview with two columns one is textboxcolumn and other is Combobox column. In that I want to change the selected Index of combobox when 1st textbox column value is changed in the same row. 
for example if i enter 2 in textbox cell then in next cell combobox(Products) selected value is 2 in same row. Please help me with code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to handle `CellValueChanged` event with something like this:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex == TextColumn.Index && ComboBoxColumn.Items.Count >0)
        {
            int itemIndex = GetCorrectItem();
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ComboBoxColumn.Index].Value = ComboBoxColumn.Items[itemIndex];

        }
    }
```

And the GetCorrectItem() method should grab the correct item index as per your specific implementation.

If you want update the combobox while typing in the textbox not after exiting, then you'll need to handle the `EditingControlShowing` event and handle the `TextChanged` event of the Editing control. something like the following:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == TextColumn.Index)
        {
            var textbox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (textbox != null)
            {
                textbox.TextChanged += textboxColumn_TextChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void textboxColumn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int itemIndex = GetCorrectItem();
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[ComboBoxColumn.Index].Value = ComboBoxColumn.Items[itemIndex];
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this one but i got error as - Following exception occurred in th DataGridView.                                                                                                System.FormatException: DataGridViewCoboBoxCell value is not Valid.                                                                                                          Plx Tel me the solution for this. Thanx for reply.